# Why this returns an empty array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a parent component of many components that I switch between them by clicking at  elements. These files are Vue files.

What I want is make them active whenever the component is being used.

As example:

When I click at Home from navbar, the component switches to Home's component(Already done that) AND makes it have a border so that it is marked as the active component(active tab as some say)

I wanted to do that by these steps:

First) I get the collection of all  elements

Second) I keep the elements that have class = current data(which is the data that I use to switch them between) by using filter. Which should be only 1 item which is the active one.

Third) Apply the CSS style to that element...etc

This is the parent component's code(I cut down CSS style btw to make it shorter):

```
<template>
  <div id="grid">
    <nav id="navbar">

      <ul id="nav">
        <a href="#" class="Home" @click="current = 'Home'" ><li>{{navbar.Home}}</li></a>        
        <a href="#" class="Reservation" @click="current = 'Reservation'" ><li>{{navbar.Reservation}}</li></a>
        <a href="#" class="About-us" @click="current = 'About-us'" ><li>{{navbar.About}}</li></a>
        <a href="#" class="Contact" @click="current = 'Contact'" ><li>{{navbar.Contact}}</li></a>
      </ul>

      <div class="button"> <!-- Make some animation of this button becomes an extendable window of singing up. Don't forget  -->
        <a href="#">Sign Up
        </a>
      </div>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/8b/fa/5d/8bfa5d6a52a03e83b995fec69a4d8c2c.jpg" alt="" id="logo">
    </nav>      

    <main id="content"> 
      <keep-alive>
        <transition name="component-fade" mode="out-in">
          <component v-bind:is="current"></component>    
        </transition>      
      </keep-alive>        
    </main>      

    <footer>
      <p>Copyright © All Rights Reserved</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Home from "./components/Home.vue";
import Aboutus from "./components/About us.vue";
import Contact from "./components/Contact.vue";
import Reservation from "./components/Reservation.vue";
import Signup from "./components/Signup.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Home: Home,
    "About-us": Aboutus,
    Contact: Contact,
    Reservation: Reservation,
    Signup: Signup
  },
  data() {
    return {
      navbar: {
        Home: "Home",
        Reservation: "Reservation",
        About: "About us",
        Contact: "Contact"
      },
      current: "Home"
    };
  },
  methods: {}
};
let nodlist = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
console.log(nodlist);
let active = Array.from(nodlist).filter(
  element => element.className == this.data.current
);
console.log(active);
active.cssText = "border-bottom: 5px solid #5fb0e4;";
</script>
```

The problem is that the array returns empty and the style doesn't apply. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure everything's initialized as the page loads? Try either calling the functions in the mounted() lifecycle hook. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: add a `console.log(element.className)` inside the `filter` function, and see what's the value.

Comment: @Devilscomrade I tried it in mounted, nothing works. Also I'm sure everything's initialized because console.log(nodlist) returns an array of actual elements

Comment: @Programmer It doesn't show anything. Actually, console.log(element) shows nothing at all.

Comment: If you change the condition in the `filter` to `element.className != this.data.current`, do you get all the elements?

Comment: @Programmer Nope. It shows nothing too.

Comment: what `Array.from(nodlist)` gives you (without the `filter`)?

Comment: @Programmer it gives me an empty array(length of 0):                                     []
cssText
:
"border-bottom: 5px solid #5fb0e4;"
length
:
0
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: I'm talking about before the `filter` function. after the `console.log(nodlist);` add `console.log(Array.from(nodlist));`

Comment: @Programmer I know that. And it showed me an empty array.

Comment: @Programmer After I applied this code:       let nodlist = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
      console.log(nodlist);
      let list = [...nodlist];
      list.forEach(element => console.log(element)); It showed me all <a> elements with their classes.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. With Vue template and script you are composing virtual DOM. Vue just doesn't work the way you are expecting. Try this:

```
...
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      navbar: {
        Home: "Home",
        Reservation: "Reservation",
        About: "About us",
        Contact: "Contact"
      },
      current: "Home"
    };
  },
  methods: {},
  // this method, lifecycle hook, is executed
  // after the Browser DOM is patched with
  // Virtual DOM you composed from template
  mounted () {
    let nodlist = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    console.log(nodlist);
    let active = Array.from(nodlist).filter(
      element => element.className == this.data.current
    );
    console.log(active);
    active.cssText = "border-bottom: 5px solid #5fb0e4;";
  }
};
```

Now your array will be not empty. But you achieved ... nothing. Vue have no idea you changed the Browser DOM and your changes will be lost with next DOM patching. Sorry bro, you just don't get the Vue idea. You have to learn more about Vue principles.

Comment: What this has anything to do with virtual DOM? The reason why it doesn't work is because it returns an empty array which means didn't find the elements, I found a fix for it later but it didn't work because the style will be kept everytime I press something so it wouldn't work like I want. Vue is still Javascript and DOM. Nothing is different in both.